# git release management model : releases always from master branch?

Tags: git, git-svn

I am reading up http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/ which seems very promising.

I am looking for a few clarifications which are kind of missing from this piece:

1. Releases are always made from master - is that right? I may have a hotfix branch or release branch but the release is made from the master. So before a release get the branch merged to master, tag it and then make the release. Keeps life simple for me but I am not sure that's what gitflow is recommending too.
2. Tags always exist on the master branch for this precise reason. Each tag marks a release point. Is that OK too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes
2. Yes

This is a quote from that [post](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/), in the section "Finishing a release branch":

> When the state of the release branch is ready to become a real release, some actions need to be carried out. First, the release branch is merged into master (since every commit on master is a new release by definition, remember). Next, that commit on master must be tagged for easy future reference to this historical version